# Could there be a correlation between the Island of Stability and dark matter?

Tags: nuclear-physics, dark-matter

I can only boast of my passion for science and not of any credentials. I ask because I am curious, and it is not the type of question one can easily Google! What if the key to discovering and unlocking the secrets of dark matter and energy lie in the [Island of Stability](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Island_of_stability)? Am I missing a vital reason that outright contradicts an attempted connection between the two?

Comment: "Am I missing a vital reason that outright contradicts an attempted connection between the two?"

Stable ultraheavy nuclei, if they exist, would still interact with light since they are composed of ordinary protons and neutrons. We would be able to see them.

Comment: That's for dark matter, which is a form of matter (if not heavy nuclei). Note that dark energy is a completely different thing: an energy density of *empty* space. It is unfortunate that people gave them such similar names. Try not to confuse the two.

Answer (score 5):

The main thing we know about dark matter is that it *does not interact electromagnetically*. That is what makes it "dark": it neither emits nor occludes light in any band.

Heavy nuclei (with or without electrons) would interact electromagnetically just like all other nuclei and atoms. We'd see their spectra imposed on all extra-galactic light: we couldn't miss it.

So, ***no***. Not a chance.

Comment: Excellent, thank you! I figured that there would be a fundamental explanation for why or why not, and that I would discover more by asking. I don't regret this learning experience! And I will be adding electromagnetism to my list of topics to learn more about.

Comment: We currently don't know any interactions. Anyway, this doesn't means that such interactions couldn't exists. For example [read this](https://www.sciencedaily.com/releases/2017/10/171026103110.htm). So, it is wise not using bold **no** when talking about undiscovered areas of physics even more when talking about the interactions of two undiscovered areas... :)